# Mac OS :: DB2 is up and running. But unable to find port

Tags: macos, configuration, db2, port, db2-luw

I installed DB2 Express-C on my mac and able to create databases, schemas successfully.

```
      [a4370397:~]: ps -ef | grep -i db2
       502 24907     1   0  8:59AM ??         0:00.06 db2wdog
       502 24908 24907   0  8:59AM ??         0:02.03 db2sysc
       502 24909 24908   0  8:59AM ??         0:00.00 db2ckpw
       502 24910 24908   0  8:59AM ??         0:00.00 db2ckpw
       502 24911 24908   0  8:59AM ??         0:00.00 db2ckpw
       502 24912 24907   0  8:59AM ??         0:00.05 db2vend (PD Vendor Process - 1)
       502 24927 24907   0  8:59AM ??         0:01.03 db2acd 
       0 54414 54369   0  9:33AM ttys004    0:00.02 su db2user
       502 54567 54443   0  9:33AM ttys004    0:00.00 grep -i db2
```

But I couldn't find the port where the db2 instance is running. SVCENAME is displayed as blank in configuration.

```
      [a4370397:/opt/db2]: db2 get dbm cfg

      Database Manager Configuration
      Node type = Database Server with local and remote clients

      TCP/IP Service name                          (SVCENAME) = 
      Discovery mode                               (DISCOVER) = SEARCH
      Discover server instance                (DISCOVER_INST) = ENABLE
```

I tried **db2set DB2COMM=tcpip** and restarted the instance but still couldn't identify the port.

Please suggest how to configure/view the port information for db2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SVCENAME` configuration parameter has not been set, so you have not told DB2 what port to listen on.

You need to update the value and restart the instance:

```
db2 update dbm config using svcename 50000
db2stop force
db2start
```

You can also use a port name corresponding to an entry in `/etc/services` for the `SVCENAME` configuration parameter.

Comment: Thanks. 
I have tried the same before but restarted without the force option. Its working now!